# the USE OF CAST FUNCTION IN THE FOLLOWING QUERY

Tags: sql, if-statement, casting

the thing is to replace whatever observation that hold the number 999.9 as NULL
but i dont know the utility of CAST here as i know it helps change the data type but WDSP in the description is STRING

```
IF(
    wdsp="999.9",
    NULL,
    CAST(wdsp AS Float64)) AS wind_speed,
```

nothing yet the cast should it come before IF or within IF

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (IF isn't standard SQL.)

Comment: Do you mean you want 999,9 instead of NULL, or vice versa NULL instead of 999,9?

Comment: Pls specify what sql dialect you're using

Answer (score 0):

The `CAST` function in being used to convert the `wdsp` column to a number (specifically `FLOAT64`) instead of returning it as a `STRING` (which you mention is the declared type). This is likely so that whatever is issuing the query can get the aliased column `wind_speed` as a numerical type that can be processed as a number and not a string.